# Can i make a animation using animation list in only xml without java?

Tags: android

I want to make animation using animation list in Xml without using the java.That is my anim xml file using animation list located at drawable folder that i have manually created.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:oneshot="false" >

<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/a1"
    android:duration="250"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/a5"
    android:duration="250"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/a2"
    android:duration="250"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/a6"
    android:duration="250"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/a3"
    android:duration="250"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/a7"
    android:duration="250"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/a4"
    android:duration="250"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/a8"
    android:duration="250"/>
```

Below is my animation xml file that whose image view source is anim.xml file

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical" >
<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#FADEAA"
    android:contentDescription="@string/Convert"
    android:src="@drawable/anim"/></LinearLayout>
```

And here is the java where i am calling the animaton layout

```
   if (id == R.id.animation) {
        setContentView(R.layout.animation);
    }`
```

Comment: "Can i make a animation using animation list in only xml without java?" -- yes, as you have already done it. If you are encountering some sort of problem, **explain what the problem is**.

Comment: i have given the code above. It is not working.It is showing just the starting image.@CommonsWare

Comment: Try `android:background` instead of `android:src`.

Comment: it is still not working. @CommonsWare

Comment: how exactly do you want it to be or do..in terms of animating

Comment: i just want to do  frame by frame animation in xml and just calling the layout in the java .